# Cancel UIGestureRecognizer if subview contains gesture?

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I was originally using the `UITouch` methods (`touchesMoved: withEvent:`) in order to detect the movement in a view. Due to the fact that it seemed not to update often enough I switched to using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` (though this didn't actually fix the initial problem).

After using this the touches received for movements responded no matter what it was touching (different subviews) which I actually prefer.  However now I have an issue with all the subviews which have movement.  I need the gesture recognizer to still move the view even while touching subviews, however if the subview also moves in this direction (left/right) I need my recognizer to cancel.

It seems like `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` might be somewhere to start, but in my case, I cannot account for all subviews.

Is it possible to make pan gesture recognizer cancel if the subview (i.e. another pan recognizer, `UISlider`, horizontal scrollview, etc.) touched needs to be moved in left/right directions without having to account for each subview individually?

Comment: Can't you use `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate -gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`?

Comment: So is your issue that when the main view's recognizer is tracking a touch, and that touch crosses into a subview that also responds to horizontal drag gestures, you want the main view's recognizer to stop tracking it, and the subview to start handling the touch instead? If yes, does the main view need to pick up tracking after the touch crosses out of the subview? I ask because I made a sample project that seemed in line with the situation you describe, but didn't reproduce the issue. I have a main view with a pan gesture recognizer, and then inside that I have (cont'd)...

Comment: (cont'd)...subviews that include a scroll view that scrolls horizontally, a uislider, a view with a pan gesture recognizer, and a view with no gesture recognizer. Touching on any of the first three and dragging causes the behavior you want to happen - the main view's recognizer isn't triggered but the sub view responds (either it scrolls, or the gesture is recognized, or the slider value is changed). When touching the view with no gesture recognizer the main view's recognizer triggers. Did I misunderstand the situation you're in and what you want to happen?

Comment: Yes this is what I'm trying to accomplish, and no I don't think I want the mainview to pic up again after leaving a subview

Comment: @RiDan I just saw your twitter comment today, sorry about that! Did you ever find a solution to this? I'll try to dig up my solution and see if it fit your needs after all...

Comment: @CarlVeazey I ended up using `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` but it would only allow me to do what I want for specific objects or classes.  it caused a few problems and in the end I used a method that was more specific and checked a for a certain instance  so I currently don't have it working exactly as Iwould like it (i.e. `UISlider` still doesn't work). So what I have works, but it isn't preferred, I'm all for an all around solution if you got it.